# WebRTC automatically grant access to user media

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, webrtc

I've read how to ignore the `WebRTC` popup asking for user permission for the webcam on Chrome using `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` and grant permission automatically. Is there any way of doing this in Safari and Firefox?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox set media.navigator.permission.disabled to true (or use media.navigator.streams.fake which does not require permission) in about:config.